# JavaScript: How to create new object properties/members and assign values inside a For Loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, javascript-objects, typeerror

I am trying create a function to **create and assign value to an object property/member**.  But I'm getting the error:

> **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined**

The function is *suppose* to **create a property/member** called **'id'**, and it is also *suppose* to **assign a value** to the newly created property/member.

```
    var add_Ids = function(array,index) {
        for(var iii = 1; iii <= 3; iii++) {
            array[index+iii].id = (array[index].id * 4)+iii;
        }
        array[index].id *= 4;
    };
```

`array` is the array that I pass into the function.

`index` is the position in the array to start on with the For Loop

P.S.  The For Loop is not overwriting anything important.
The element that corresponds to "`array[index+iii]`" is empty.

Comment: If "The element that corresponds to "array[index+iii]" is empty." actually means "`array[index+iii]` is undefined", this *seems* self-explanatory.

Comment: (Well, it could also be `array[index]`..)

Comment: So what you trying to achieve with this?

Answer (score 0):

```
array[index+iii].id = (array[index].id * 4)+iii;
```

In that, If `array[index+iii]` is `undefined` before, Then `array[index+iii].id` would give that error you've mentioned.

So before accessing `id` check whether the property exists.

```
if(!array[index+iii]) array[index+iii] = {}; // initializing if its not present.
array[index+iii].id = (array[index].id * 4)+iii;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things at play here.

An array element must exist before it can be manipulated. Consider this code -

```
var my = []; 
my[0].id = 1; // TypeError: Cannot set property 'id' of undefined
```

This is because exactly as the error states, my[0] is undefined here. Since your array is passed into a function, do one of the following (depends upon the circumstances/requirements of this function):

- Ensure that you only pass in arrays that will meet the criteria of your function. In this case, your function expects an array with 3 elements of indices [iii+index,iii+index+3].
- Ensure that the count you pass in doesn't cause your operation to exceed the length of the passed in array.
- Fail with a meaningful error message - test for undefined and if so, generate a meaningful error.
- If this matches what you are doing, you can check for `undefined` and make a default option if needed.

Example of the last:

```
var add_ids = function(array, index) { 
    for (var i = 1, i <= 3; i++) { 
        if (!array[index + i]) { 
            array[index + i] = generateDefaultObject(); 
        }
        array[index + i].id = (array[index].id * 4) + i;
    }
    array[index].id *= 4
}
```

Second, it seems as though that you expect this to work. It is similar to JavaScript's implicit global declaration. For example:

```
my = 4; // my didn't exist before this line, but now does as a global
```

is (unfortunately) valid JavaScript. Arrays do not support this kind of declaration for elements - they need to exist before you work with them.